# `content: ''` vs `content: none`

Tags: css, cross-browser

I was reading through Eric Meyer's CSS reset and saw this:

```
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    /* ? */ content: '';
    /* ? */ content: none;
}
```

I assume that some browsers support `content: ''` and some `content: none`, is this the case? And which browsers support which?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Meyer credits Paul Chaplin with that version of the blockquote/q reset styles.

Chaplin's [post](http://www.paulchaplin.com/blog/css-reset-and-quirky-quotes) on the subject contains the following style block, helpfully annotated.

```
blockquote, q
{
    quotes: none;
}

/*
Safari doesn't support the quotes attribute, so we do this instead.
*/
blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after
{
    /*
    CSS 2; used to remove quotes in case "none" fails below.
    */
    content: "";
    /*
    CSS 2.1; will remove quotes if supported, and override the above.
    User-agents that don't understand "none" should ignore it, and
    keep the above value. This is here for future compatibility,
    though I'm not 100% convinced that it's a good idea...
    */
    content: none;
}
```

To boil it down: current versions of most browsers simply support a `quotes: none` style, which eliminates the need to use the `:before` and `:after` selectors. The odd man out was Safari/WebKit, which didn't respect `quotes: none`. The next way to solve this was with the `:before`/`:after` pseudo-elements, but at the time of that writing, WebKit didn't support `content: none` either, so `content: ""` was required.

However, that post was in 2008, and a [quick test](http://jsfiddle.net/VpsCd/2/) with current WebKit browsers (Safari 5.1 and Chrome 12) shows that `quotes: none` works fine on both. The [`content: none` bug against WebKit](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=20032) is still open for some reason, while the [bug for the quotes property](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=6503) was closed fairly recently.

So, long story short, the extra styles appear to be there to support older versions of Safari (and possibly Chrome). It's a little more difficult to nail down exactly when they got support, but current versions of all browsers seem to deal with `quotes: none` (and `content: none`) just fine.

Comment: So there's no *real* benefit to using `content: none`?

Comment: `content: none` and `content: ""` aren't quite the same. `content: none` is for explicitly preventing the `before` or `after` pseudo-element from being generated (really only used to override another style that would have generated content), while `content: ""` does create the extra elements, but they're empty. As for *real* benefit, a combination of styles on `:before: or `:after` would make the difference visible (like some padding and a background color), but it's probably more down to "purity" or "correctness". At any rate, there's no harm to having `content: none` for supporting browsers.

Comment: just to say I came across this when overriding a previous style. I found that content "" definitely carried some of the previous styles with it and content "none" didn't work in the ipad that I use to test with (as suggested in the comment above). I used display none on the pseudo-element as a "belt and braces" override (rather than having to reset every style)

Comment: Though this topic is ancient, in case it helps someone today: Safari now supports `content: none`, and this is useful and preferred over `content: ''`. I was trying to override (or, really, suppress) an inherited `::before` style using `content: ''`, but this did not work--- it did not fully suppress/remove the inherited `::before` styles. But `display: none` did. NOTE ALSO that *Chrome and Edge behave differently* from Safari in this instance. For Chrome and Edge, `display: ''` *did* fully remove the inherited `::before` styles.